# Publishing posts in wordpress without XML-RPC in Python

Tags: python, wordpress, python-requests, xml-rpc, robobrowser

In the past I used the [python-wordpress-xmlrpc](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library to publish posts on Wordpress and it all went fine but lately there have been enormous flooding attacks on the blog using the XML-RPC.php file.
Since I'm forced to disable the API, I'm looking for a convenient way to still publish posts via python script.
I tried RoboBrowser but it lacks AJAX functionality. I also tried the Requests module but I suck at analysing network traffic especially when it comes to HTTP requests and AJAX and therefore I can't get it working the way I want ;)
So if you know how to work with Wordpress and the requests module, please help out :)

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    login_url = 'http://example.com/wp/wp-login.php'
    new_post_url = 'http://example.com/wp/wp-admin/post-new.php'
    user = 'user'
    pw = 'password'
    params = {'log': user, 'pwd': pw}
    headers = {'Referer':'http://example.com/wp/wp-login.php', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':1}
    l = c.request('POST', login_url, data=params, allow_redirects=True)#headers=headers,
    np = c.request('GET', new_post_url)
```

This code gets me to login wordpress and create a new post but since there are a whole lot of AJAX requests going on when entering title, content, choosing categories, etc. I'm quite overwhelmed how to process these data entries and finally publish the post.

Comment: Asking for external resources modules/libraries is considered as an Off topic question!

Comment: I would recommend you to post a sample code describing your problem, it will certainly help others to provide you a solutions or suggestions!

Comment: Added source code :)